# Python assign text to new variable

Tags: python, list, variables

In Python, I am using BeautifulSoup to parse text.  I want to save a set of 'str' objects into a list.  The following code won't run, but the idea should come across:

```
listings = soup.find_all('h6')
for i in listings:
    projecturls[i] = i.find_all('a', href=True)[0]['href']
```

So I want to cycle through the elements 'listings' and extract a string.  I then want to save this string into projecturls, which I want to be a list.  But I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'projecturls' is not defined
```

How do I define this? Or is there a better way to do what I want?

I suppose that dynamically defining N variables would also work, but it is not preferred.

Comment: It looks like 'projecturls' is a dictionary. Add `projecturls={}` right above that loop to inittialize this loop.

Comment: Did you define `projecturls`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `projecturls` as a list object, then use `list.append` method to add an item there:

```
listings = soup.find_all('h6')
projecturls = [] # <-------------
for i in listings:
    url = i.find_all('a', href=True)[0]['href']
    projecturls.append(url) # <------
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use list comprehension:

```
listings = soup.find_all('h6')
projecturls = [i.find_all('a', href=True)[0]['href'] for i in listings]
```

Or `map` function:

```
listings = soup.find_all('h6')
projecturls = list(map(lambda i: i.find_all('a', href=True)[0]['href'], listings))
```